# upload excel using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, excel, alamofire

i try to upload an excel file using alamofire in iOS. my file path is

```
file:///Users/macbook/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/75477755-3367-41DE-B3D2-A2E22C7AE069/data/Containers/Data/Application/45CB65D0-0B7C-4F17-89AA-2163301F2E6B/Documents/appImportContacts.xls
```

and the code I use

```
    // import Alamofire
func uploadWithAlamofire(filePath : String ) {

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)//"/foo/bar/file.text")
    let dirUrl = url.deletingLastPathComponent()
    print(dirUrl.path)
    // Output: /foo/bar

    let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "appImportContacts", withExtension: "xls", subdirectory: dirUrl.path)

    Alamofire.upload(fileURL!, to: "http://192.168.1.213/api/app/UploadExcelFile").responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

I get fileURL nil

How can I make my file path as Bundle to pass to alamofire?

Alamofire version:4
Xcode version:8.2.1
Swift version:3
Platform(s) running Alamofire:iOS
macOS version running Xcode:10

Comment: Forget about the directory. Just use the Bundle.url method for a resource file without specifying the subdirectory: it's the responsability of Bundle.url to find its location, not yours. // Also check that the file is actually copied (not referenced) in the project, and check that it has the same target as the app.

Comment: I used let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "appImportContacts", withExtension: "xls") but fileURl is nil

Comment: It means that either the file is actually not in the Bundle, or that it does not have the right target.

Comment: let me explain, I download the file from internet and modify it and then I want to upload . Am i right by getting file with bundle or I have to do sth else?

Comment: Ah. Well indeed you're doing it wrong. Using Bundle.url is for a file that is embedded in the project! Not for downloaded files....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

```
//
//  HowToDownloadViewController.swift
//  WhiteSms
//
//  Created by MacBook on 7/26/1396 AP.
//  Copyright © 1396 AP IPE. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FileExplorer
import Alamofire
import HandyJSON
import SwiftyJSON

class ImportExcelViewController: UIViewController, FileExplorerViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)



}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func onDownload_Click(_ sender: Any) {


    // Create destination URL
    let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("appImportContacts.xls")

    //Create URL to the source file you want to download
    let fileURL = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.213/downloads/appImportContacts.xls")

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
            }

            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    task.resume()



}

@IBAction func onUpload_Click(_ sender: Any) {
    let fileExplorer = FileExplorerViewController()
    fileExplorer.canRemoveFiles = true //specify whether user is allowed to remove files
    fileExplorer.canRemoveDirectories = false //specify whether user is allowed to remove directories


    fileExplorer.delegate = self
    self.present(fileExplorer, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

public func fileExplorerViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: FileExplorerViewController) {

}

public func fileExplorerViewController(_ controller: FileExplorerViewController, didChooseURLs urls: [URL]) {
    //Your code here
    print(urls)

    var fileAddress = urls[0]

    uploadWithAlamofire(filePath: urls[0].absoluteString)

}

// import Alamofire
func uploadWithAlamofire(filePath : String ) {

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)//"/foo/bar/file.text")
    let dirUrl = url.deletingLastPathComponent()
    print(dirUrl.path+"/appImportContacts.xls")
    // Output: /foo/bar



    let filePath = dirUrl.path+"/appImportContacts.xls"

    var bytes = [UInt8]()

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {

        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: data.length)
        data.getBytes(&buffer, length: data.length)
        bytes = buffer
    }


    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {
        multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(Data(fromArray: bytes), withName: "appImportContacts",fileName: "appImportContacts.xls", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
    },
                     to:"http://192.168.1.213/api/app/UploadExcelFile")
    {
        (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value)
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
}
}
extension Data {

init<T>(fromArray values: [T]) {
    var values = values
    self.init(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &values, count: values.count))
}

func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return self.withUnsafeBytes {
        [T](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: self.count/MemoryLayout<T>.stride))
    }
}
}
```